# Symfony - Swiftmailer spool send an email several number of times

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have a CRON Job which sends the emails. It creates about thousands of unique emails to send daily.

I have configured it like below:

```
*/1 * * * * php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --message-limit=100 --time-limit=20 --env=prod >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And clear failure is set after five minutes.

These simultaneous calls cause the multiple sending of the same email. So today, one user will receive multiple same emails even if I have only one entry in my database.

Please, let us know of any solution.